# Listview fill method gets an error

Tags: c#

What's wrong with my code? This code is from my VB .NET program which I converted to C# but gets an error.. It is used to to SELECT data from database with the use of LIKE for searching.. Here is my code:

```
public void byItemCode(ListView LV, String SearchBox)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ItemCode, Title, Genre, Film, YearReleased, Classification, NumberOfDiscs FROM tblDVDInventory WHERE ItemCode LIKE '%" + SearchBox + "%' ORDER BY Title", con);
                da.Fill(dt);

                int num = 1;

                for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; ctr++)
                {
                    ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem();
                    Item.Text = num;
                    Item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[ctr]["ItemCode"]);
                    Item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[ctr]["Title"]);
                    Item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[ctr]["Genre"]);
                    Item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[ctr]["Film"]);
                    Item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[ctr]["YearReleased"]);
                    Item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[ctr]["Classification"]);
                    Item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[ctr]["NumberOfDiscs"]);
                    LV.Items.Add(Item);

                    num = num + 1;
                }

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
            }
        }
```

and then on the Search Form, here is the code:

```
var Search = new SearchMethods();

                if (cmbSearchBy.Text == "Item Code")
                {
                    lvwInventory.Items.Clear();
                    Search.byItemCode(lvwInventory, txtSearch.Text);
                }
```

I wonder how to do this the right way in C#? Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to initialize SubItems

Comment: Quite possibly Joe's answer, but you should probably post the error if you want an exact answer.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubCollectionItems.(Add)String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Datatable will be filled with `Object`s, not `string`s. `ListView` wants `string`s, so you need to call `ToString()` or typecast to `string` type. Use `ToString()` if you don't know what types to expect or if you don't expect `string`s; use `(string)` casting if you expect a `string`.

Comment: I get it now, its just that I have to add ToString() to each rows that I add like this:

Item.Text = num.ToString();
                    Item.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[ctr]["ItemCode"].ToString());